# jQuery mobile data role slider doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I am using latest jQuery mobile 1.0.1 and I am using data-role=slider on my second page which load after the transition from first page. This data-role slider doesn't seems to work on second page. When I run that page independently then it works but doesn't when it loads after transition from first page. I have checked the debug also and there is not javascript error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using data-role="page" on second page?Can you post your first page code?

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code. It works fine for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Single page template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="one">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Single page</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
      <p>This is a single page boilerplate template that you can copy to build you first jQuery Mobile page. Each link or form from here will pull a new page in via Ajax to support the animated page transitions.</p>
      <p>Just view the source and copy the code to get started. All the CSS and JS is linked to the jQuery CDN versions so this is super easy to set up. Remember to include a meta viewport tag in the head to set the zoom level.</p>

      <p>This template is standard HTML document with a single "page" container inside, unlike a <a href="multipage-template.html" data-ajax="false">multi-page template</a> that has multiple pages within it. We strongly recommend building your site or app
        as a series of separate pages like this because it's cleaner, more lightweight and works better without JavaScript.</p>
      <p><a href="#two" data-role="button">Show page "two"</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer content</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

  </div>
  <!-- /page -->

  <!-- Start of second page: #two -->
  <div data-role="page" id="two" data-theme="a" data-transition="slider">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Two</h1>

    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
      <label for="flip-a">Select slider:</label>
      <select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Two</h2>
      <p>I have an id of "two" on my page container. I'm the second page container in this multi-page template.</p>
      <p>Notice that the theme is different for this page because we've added a few <code>data-theme</code> swatch assigments here to show off how flexible it is. You can add any content or widget to these pages, but we're keeping these simple.</p>
      <p><a href="#one" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Back to page "one"</a></p>

    </div>
    <!-- /content -->


    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->
  </div>
  <!-- /page two -->
</body>

</html>
```